# pytest works in cmd but not in pycharm

Tags: pytest

i've started using pytest recently but unfortunately I got some problems with it:
let's say for example that I made a python file called "car.py" and a test file called "_test_car.py" that I've put in the same directory.
when I try to run the test in PyCharm it doesn't print anything but when I open cmd and type "pytest [test_path] it shows me the results.
How can I fix this issue?

I tried unistall and install again the module of pytest but it didn't work

Comment: is your pycharm console definitely navigated to the right directory?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Although the steps provided is not adequate, here is my suggestion.
1. Edit Configuration in Pycharm, set interpreter
2. rename to `test_car.py`